# Scraping Reddit for Data Related to Illicit Drug Trends

Tags: r, web-scraping, reddit

I am a bio-analytical chemist and work in the field of drug analysis, specifically with NPS and internet bought pseudo-pharmaceutical products. I am brand new to the world of web scraping, with limited knowledge of R or programming. My aim is to scrape Reddit between 2015-2023 to analyse drug trends (sales, use, supply, harm reduction strategies); I have read many posts here regarding R as a perfect platform, but I am not sure if this will work for the research I am driving. Please could I ask this community for guidance. Thank you.

So far I have just tried to use the reddit standard search function, but this is limited, and the results are not malleable.

Comment: There is a R package which is called `RedditExtractoR`. You can try this?

Comment: I found that there is a blog which is related to your topic: https://rpubs.com/tanlan/redditapi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.